# Why is a string copy function just assigning the pointer not working?

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

Consider this implementation of `strcpy`:

```
void my_strcpy(char target[], char source[])
{
   target = source;
}

int main(void)
{
   char target[20];
   char source[] = "Source String";

   my_strcpy(target, source);
   printf("Target: %s", target);

   return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work and its made me question my understanding of strings and arrays in C.

Here's my reasoning: `target` and `source` are really just pointers to the first elements of arrays, ie. `target == &target[0]` and `source == &source[0]`.  When I set `target = source`, I'm pointing the pointer `target` at the same memory address where the pointer `source` is pointed at.

Now when I `printf` `target`, it should also print `"Source String"`.  But it doesn't.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Are you expecting `source` to be copied into `target` or `target` to be assigned the address of `source`? Both are wrong, BTW.

Comment: Note that C uses [lexical scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scope_vs._dynamic_scope). The `target` variable in `my_strcpy` is in a different scope than the `target` variable in `main`. Hence, they are not the same variable, even though you gave them the same name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
void my_strcpy(char target[], char source[])
{
   target = source;
}
```

What you do here is, as you wrote, pass the pointers to the function. But the pointers themselves are passed *by value*, so the function has it's local copies of these pointers. The `target` inside the function stops existing as soon es the function exits.

To actually modify pointers in a function, you would have to pass a *pointer to this pointer*, e.g. like this:

```
void my_strcpy(char *target[], char source[])
{
   *target = source;
}
```

Note that this still wouldn't work with your program, because in `main()` you declare an array. The address of a declared array cannot be changed. This is because an array is *not* the same as a pointer (as you can often read in poorly written C tutorials) but is just implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element when you pass it to a function. So, writing `char *target` in your `main()`, this *would* work, calling the function like `my_strcpy(&target, source);`.

Also note that this is in **no way** a copy, so the naming of your function is semantically wrong. A real copy function would look like this:

```
void my_strcpy(char *target, const char *source)
{
   while (*target++ = *source++);
}
```

copying the individual characters until hitting a `\0` character (then the expression would evaluate to `0` and the while loop would stop). This super-simple implementation leaves the burden to provide enough storage for `target` and to make sure `source` is actually *0-terminated* to the caller, but it is indeed more or less what the standard C library's `strcpy()` does.

**edit**: I just changed your function signature a bit -- the first change is a matter of taste, replacing `identifier[]` by `*identifier`. I like to do this because this is what happens internally anyways, so it makes clearer what the function actually takes. The second one is adding a `const` where appropriate: Your function never changes what is pointed to by `source`, so you should make this explicit -- this way the compiler can catch more errors for you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, I just added a few things in the hope future readers might profit!

Answer (score 5):

Two things you need to keep in mind:

- C uses [pass-by-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value).
- You cannot change the address of an automatic array.

Now,

```
my_strcpy(target, source);
```

is the same as

```
my_strcpy(&target[0], &source[0]);
```

which passes the address of first element of both the arrays and

```
void my_strcpy(char target[], char source[])
```

is the same as

```
void my_strcpy(char* target, char* source)
```

where `target` points to the address of the first element of the array `target` in `main` and `source` points to the address of the first element of the array `source` in `main`.

So,

```
target = source;
```

simply changes the location where `target` points to. Now, both `target` and `source` points to the same memory location, i.e, to the address of the array `source` in `main`. **This doesn't have any effect on either of the arrays in `main` as C uses pass-by-value.** Both the pointers in the function have different addresses as that of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this makes sense.