# Setting value of string in function does not work

Tags: c

```
void func(char *var) 
{
    var = "Hello"; 
}

int main () {
   char var[10];
   func(var);
   printf ("var is %s", var);
}
```

Why doesn't the above code work in C? (printf displays nothing).
Changing `var = "hello;"` to `strcpy(var, "hello");` fixes it:

```
void func (char *var) 
{
    strcpy(var, "HELLO");
}
```

Comment: Why does `void func(int i) {i = 7;} int main() {int x = 5; f(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}` print 5 instead of 7?

Comment: that's clearly passed by value. In my code above just changing the direct assignment (=) to an strcpy fixes the issue. The function prototype is still the same and takes a character pointer: func (char * var).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is a string copy function just assigning the pointer not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547413/why-is-a-string-copy-function-just-assigning-the-pointer-not-working)

Comment: very similar. strcpy is not suggested or discussed though and I am trying  to assign a string literal to the character pointer (not copying from an array to another or trying to change their addresses)

Answer (score 2):

Because `var = "Hello"` modifies the argument `var`. Arguments are stored in new variables - this doesn't modify the value of the other variable (also called `var`) in `main`.

In other words, it doesn't work for the same reason this doesn't work:

```
void func(int i)
{
    i = 7;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    func(i);
    printf ("var is %i", var);
}
```

Now, consider these two functions (and a global variable):

```
int five = 5;

void func1(int *p)
{
    p = &five;
}

void func2(int *p)
{
    *p = five;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("%d\n", i); // prints 0 (duh)
    func1(&i);
    printf("%d\n", i); // still prints 0
    func2(&i);
    printf("%d\n", i); // prints 5
}
```

Do you know the difference? `func1` modifies `p` itself (by setting it to the address of `five`). `p` is a local variable in `func1`, so there's no reason that changing it would affect anything in `main`.

On the other hand, `func2` modifies *the thing `p` points to*. And `p` points to the local variable `i` in `main` - so this one *does* modify `i` in `main`!

Now consider these functions:

```
void func3(char *s)
{
    s = "Hello";
}
void func4(char *s)
{
    strcpy(s, "Hello");
}
```

The string literal (`"Hello"`) is a red herring here, so let's mostly remove it from the equation:

```
char hello_string[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
char *hello_string_pointer = &hello_string[0];

void func3(char *s)
{
    s = hello_string_pointer;
}
void func4(char *s)
{
    strcpy(s, hello_string_pointer);
}
```

`func3` couldn't possibly affect anything in `main`, for the same reason that `func1` can't - `s` is a local variable inside `func3`, and we're only changing `s`.

On the other hand, `func4` calls `strcpy`. Do you know what `strcpy` does? It does the equivalent of this:

```
void func4(char *s)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
        *(s + k) = *(hello_string_pointer + k);
}
```

Some pointer arithmetic there, but the point is, it modifies *the thing `s` points to`, and the 5 things after it - which are the first 6 elements of the array in`main`.

Comment: TIL that lots of code snippets can make an answer look **really** long.

Comment: thanks! where did all the previous answers to the question go though?

Comment: @codemaster I see two deleted answers, both with negative scores and both deleted by their owners. (Users with 10k rep or more can see deleted answers, if you were wondering how I can see that)

Comment: yes this is a more detailed and illustrated answer. Thanks again!